# Update table from table with general data

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL database (5.X) I have a table where info about all other tables is stored (next id etc).
Is it possible to update this table like this?
In my table "tables" there is a field "tableName" and "nextId". I want to do something like:

```
UPDATE tables SET nextId = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tables.tableName);
```

EDIT: 
I know now that it is not possible to dynamically determine the table name.
However, can I do it for each row? I can easily let all queries generate automatically.
Something like this then:

```
UPDATE tables SET nextId = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableX);
```

I will let this query generate for each row in my tables table.

Comment: No, you can't use a column value to fill in the table name in a query. Table names are always taken literally.

Comment: You can do it by using dynamic SQL in a stored procedure, using `PREPARE` to create a different `UPDATE` query for each row.

Comment: Why do you need these tables of your own? MySQL already has metadata tables in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database.

Comment: But why are you trying to something like that?!? Seems like a very odd idea.

Comment: I am trying this because I accidently ran an update on the tables table without a where clause. This means all my nextid's are wrong. I will have to manually check all tables for the next id I guess instead of doing in with one query.

Comment: If I leave the dynamic table name out of it, can I update my rows row per row? I can let the queries generate for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to let the queries generate for each row instead of in one huge query with some simple VBA in Excel:

```
Sub generate()
    For i = 1 To 107
        Cells(i, 3) = "update tables set nextId = (select max(id) from " & Cells(i, 2) & ") + 1 where soort = '" & Cells(i, 2) & "';"
    Next i
End Sub
```

This resulted in 107 queries like this one:

```
update tables set nextId = (select max(id) from table_name) + 1 where tableName = 'table_name';
```